# Configuring mitmproxy: installing cert, mitim.it, magic url not working iOS

Tags: ios, ssl, ssl-certificate, mitmproxy

I'm following [link 1](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/certinstall.html) to mitm my iPhone. I'm getting stuck at installing the mitm certificate on the phone. 
Every bit of documentation points toward going to mimt.it once you've set up mitmproxy server to install the cert. No such luck, further more the instructions to manually install a certificate on iOS point to a password protected MIT.edu domain [link 2](https://kb.mit.edu/confluence/login.action?os_destination=%2Fpages%2Fviewpage.action%3FpageId%3D152600377)

When attempting to install by going to mitim.it I get this error:

```
    [+++] PokemonGo MITM Proxy listening on 8081
    [!] Make sure to have the CA cert .http-mitm-proxy/certs/ca.pem installed on your device
    [-] PROXY_TO_SERVER_REQUEST_ERROR on /:
    [-] HTTPS_CLIENT_ERROR on :
```